# Proper nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How do you do nginx rewrite rule to convert

> example.com/?subtopic=forum&action=show_board&id=1

into this

> example.com/forum/board/1

or this

> example.com/?subtopic=characters&name=Eternal

into this

> example.com/characters/Eternal

I've found and tried to play around with this code

```
location / {
            rewrite ^/subtopic/(.*)$ /?subtopic=$1 last;
    }
```

but it doesnt work (i'm really a newbie into rewriting)

Comment: Changed rule to this `rewrite ^(.*)$ /?subtopic=characters&name=$1 last;` and its a step, it recognize something in a link, but when i try to see character page, it says _Character /Eternal does not exist._

Answer (score 0):

You may try these rules:

```
rewrite /(.*)/(.*)/(\d+) /?subtopic=$1&action=show_$2&id=$3 last;
rewrite /(.*)/(.*)       /?subtopic=$1&name=$2 last;
```

Comment: should it be still under `location / {}` ?

Comment: @Rafau it should be outside `location`.

Comment: tried that, it only works if i go into url `http://www.example.com/ban` that was before: `http://example.com/?subtopic=ban` if i try another url like for characters - it doesnt work for some reason (it might be my website, will try few things)

Comment: @Rafau try to add the 3rd rule: `rewrite /(.*) /?subtopic=$1 last;`